# How to access given object below?

Tags: php, zend-framework

How can I access "atom" from below:

```
Zend_Gdata_Calendar_EventEntry Object
(
    [_entryClassName:protected] => Zend_Gdata_Calendar_EventEntry
    [_sendEventNotifications:protected] => 
    [_timezone:protected] => 
    [_quickadd:protected] => 
    [_who:protected] => Array
        (
            [0] => Zend_Gdata_Extension_Who Object
                (
                    [_rootElement:protected] => who
                    [_email:protected] => vrock123456@gmail.com
                    [_rel:protected] => http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#event.organizer
                    [_valueString:protected] => vrock123456@gmail.com
                    [_attendeeStatus:protected] => 
                    [_attendeeType:protected] => 
                    [_entryLink:protected] => 
                    [_rootNamespace:protected] => gd
                    [_rootNamespaceURI:protected] => 
                    [_extensionElements:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [_extensionAttributes:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [_text:protected] => 
                    [_namespaces:protected] => Array
                        (
                            [atom] => Array
                                (
                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom
                                        )

                                )
                          )
                  )
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Zend_Gdata_Calendar_EventEntry` has method `getWho()`, which returns array of "whos". But in `Zend_Gdata_Extension_Who` I don't see method, which returns defined namespaces.
But you can access that property using [Reflection](http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionproperty.construct.php) - Example #2.

Answer (score 0):

1) Show Zend_Gdata_Calendar_EventEntry class

2) Possibly in foreach loop or the class may have some method like as_array() to convert an object into array.